# Checking multiple keys in redis

Tags: lua, redis

So here's an example of what the keys I have set in redis:

```
SADD group:test subgroup:1
SADD subgroup:1 user:1
SADD subgroup:1 user:2
SADD group:test subgroup:2
SADD subgroup:2 user:3
```

So what I want to achieve is that I want to find out which subgroup has space in the key `group:test` and return that. Let's say for example that the maximum users per sub group is 2.

In that case, subgroup 2 would have space so it should return `subgroup:2`.

If there isn't any space I'd like it to return the last subgroup +1. So in that case it would return `subgroup:3`.

Currently, the way this is written means that I have to use `smembers` to get the members of the `group:test` set and loop through each key using `scard`to see which sub group has space. If the loop ends and there's no space in any key, then I just add 1 to the last subgroup and use that.

Users can leave a subgroup after they have joined. I used multi to do this, but it doesn't seem very efficient as it continues running scard even after it has found space in a key. So let's say in this example `user:2` left `subgroup:1`, it would still check `subgroup:2` to see if it had space.

I'm more than willing to restructure the data if there's a way to make this work. The only thing I don't want to change is that the key for users needs to be stored within the subgroup set.

If there's a way to do this with a LUA script, I'd also be willing to do that.

I'm really looking for an efficient way to do this.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when explaining the issue. I do use SCARD to see which subgroup has space. I edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lua script isn't the way here - rewording the above requirement: we're looking for an efficient way to get the cardinality of Sets (e.g. `subgroup:1`) at any instant, and we're specifically interested in Set the one with the least members ("has space").

To do that, you keep another key in your database - lets call it `counts`. That key holds a Sorted Set data structure, where each element is the name of one of your sets and the score is the its **current** cardinality.

By "current" I mean that each `SADD`, `SREM` and `DEL` that your code performs on subgroups, needs to be coupled with the relevant `ZADD` on the `counts` key.

When you have all that in place, all that you need to do is query the key for the lowest-scored member:

```
ZRANGE counts 0 0
```

The cost in maintaining this extra structure is the complexity of updates whenever subgroup changes. Sorted Sets' operations are typically O(log(N)) so they're pretty efficient and wouldn't burden the server too much.